# Problem with import name 'Select' from 'discord'

Tags: discord, discord.py

When starting it writes an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\name\Desktop\Discord\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from discord import Select, SelectOption, ActionRow
ImportError: cannot import name 'Select' from 'discord'
```

I haven’t done programming for a long time because of my studies and now I can’t figure out how to fix this error, please help. I will be grateful

Here's the code itself:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Select, SelectOption, ActionRow

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False

users = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Вошел в систему как {bot.user}')

@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    user_id = ctx.author.id
    if user_id not in users:
        users[user_id] = {
            'games': 0,
            'currency': 0
        }
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Успешная регистрация",
            description="Вы успешно зарегистрировались!",
            color=discord.Color.green()
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Регистрация не удалась",
            description="Вы уже зарегистрированы!",
            color=discord.Color.red()
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command()
async def играть(ctx):
    options = [
        SelectOption(label="Угадай число", value="option1"),
        SelectOption(label="Option 2", value="option2"),
        SelectOption(label="Option 3", value="option3"),
    ]

    select = Select(custom_id="select_menu", placeholder="Выберите опцию", options=options)

    action_row = ActionRow(select)

    await ctx.send("Пожалуйста, выберите опцию:", components=[action_row])

@bot.event
async def on_select_option(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    if interaction.custom_id == "select_menu":
        selected_value = interaction.data["values"][0]
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Вы выбрали: {selected_value}", ephemeral=True)

@bot.command()
@commands.has_role('Chapter [10]')
async def money(ctx, action, user: discord.Member, amount: int):
    user_id = user.id
    if user_id in users:
        if action == 'выдать':
            users[user_id]['currency'] += amount
            await ctx.send(f'Вы выдали {amount} валюты пользователю {user.name}')
        elif action == 'забрать':
            if users[user_id]['currency'] >= amount:
                users[user_id]['currency'] -= amount
                await ctx.send(f'Вы забрали {amount} валюты у пользователя {user.name}')
            else:
                await ctx.send('У пользователя недостаточно валюты!')
        else:
            await ctx.send('Недопустимое действие!')
    else:
        await ctx.send('Пользователь не зарегистрирован!')

@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):
    user_id = ctx.author.id
    if user_id in users:
        games = users[user_id]['games']
        currency = users[user_id]['currency']
        registration_date = users[user_id]['registration_date']
        embed = discord.Embed(title='Статистика', color=discord.Color.blue())
        embed.add_field(name='Количество игр', value=games, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='Количество валюты', value=currency, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='Дата регистрации', value=registration_date, inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        await ctx.send('Вы не зарегистрированы!')

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

I tried many methods from the internet, but they didn’t help, I’ve been sitting for more than 2 hours searching for information and can’t figure out how to fix it, although I wrote + - half a year ago a similar code and it worked

Comment: Is this running in a virtual environment (`venv`)?

Answer (score 1):

Just import **Select** from **discord.ui** instead:

```
from discord.ui import Select
```